# Stack Tracer Login failed.The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Tags: c#

I created a login form and installed my project into another pc and when i want to login it show me the Error:The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication,I have make the integrated security = false but i still have the issue,when i dont have the login mode i can connect to it ..

My Login form code

```
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("data source=DESKTOP-Q8526KR;initial catalog=dentned;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;");
string query = "Select * from dbo.doctors Where doctors_username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and doctors_password = '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
DataTable dbdoc = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dbdoc);
if (dbdoc.Rows.Count == 1) {
    FormMain objfrmMain = new FormMain();
    this.Hide();
    if (dbdoc.Rows[0][8].ToString() != "admin") {
        objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[0].Visible = false;
        objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[2].Visible = false;
        objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[3].Visible = false;
        objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[4].Visible = false;
        objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[5].Visible = false;
        objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[8].Visible = false;

    }
    objfrmMain.Show();

}
else {
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with trying to use SSPI (`Integrated Security=True`) across workgroups or between domains.  Essentially you are trying to connect to the database using credentials that it doesn't know how to verify and it is refusing to let you in.

You need to remove the `Integrated Security=True` from your connection string and add some actual credentials.  Create a user in SQL Server, give it the rights it needs to do the job, then pass the credentials in your connection string.

I suggest that you use the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) class to modify your connection string so you have some flexibility in the way you handle the credentials.  Something like this:

```
// using System.Data.SqlClient;
const string srcConnString = "data source=DESKTOP-Q8526KR;initial catalog=dentned;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";

var csBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(srcConnString);
csBuilder.Remove("Integrated Security");
csBuilder.UserID = "somesqluser";
csBuilder.Password = "password";
var connString = csBuilder.ToString();

SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connString);
```

---

As an aside, your query composition is open to [severe abuse](https://xkcd.com/327/).  Please read up on SQL injection attacks and how to avoid them by using parameterized queries.  You'll save yourself a lot of pain and suffering in the long run.

Better yet, use and ORM like [LINQ to DB](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db), [LINQ to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/) or [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/) to access the database.  It might not be quite as fast as hand-written SQL queries (although sometimes it's faster) but it's much easier to use once you get started:

*(EF6, based on [this source code](https://github.com/davidegironi/dentned/tree/master/DentneDModel/Entity))*

```
using (var dc = new dentnedEntities())
{
    var doctor = dc.doctors.SingleOrDefault(_ => _.doctors_username == username && _ => _.doctors_password == password);
    if (doctor != null)
    {
        doctor.last_login = DateTime.Now;
        dc.SaveChanges();

        // update main form here...
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually that project i have imported login form and i have to add sql conn after i install it on other pc's ill get this error i will try add ur code ill hope it works.. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code but i think something is wrong bcuz i cannot connect

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


    {
        const string srcConnString = "data source=DESKTOP-Q8526KR;initial catalog=dentned;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";

        var csBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(srcConnString);
        csBuilder.Remove("Integrated Security");
        csBuilder.UserID = "sa";
        csBuilder.Password = "sasa";
        var connString = csBuilder.ToString();

        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(srcConnString,sqlcon);
        DataTable dbdoc = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dbdoc);
        if (dbdoc.Rows.Count == 1) 

        {
            FormMain objfrmMain = new FormMain();
            this.Hide();
            if(dbdoc.Rows[0][8].ToString()!="admin")

            {
                objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[0].Visible = false;
                objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[2].Visible = false;
                objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[3].Visible = false;
                objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[4].Visible = false;
                objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[5].Visible = false;
                objfrmMain.MainMenuStrip.Items[8].Visible = false;


            }
            objfrmMain.Show();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username-i ose passwordi eshte gabim !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }



    }
```

Comment: Stil have the same problem after i install it on other pc's ... can u please explain a little how must the login form code to connect into it